# node.js & express - res.render() reset the static html path

Tags: node.js

I get request with this:

```
app.get('/page/:no', article.home);
```

sent response with this:

```
res.render('article', {article: articleContents});
```

then the css file& script file link have been changed.Like this:

```
GET /bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 5ms (correct)
GET /page/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 3ms (wrong, I don't need '/page')
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you loading your `bootstrap.min.css` with a root-ed path? i.e

```
/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Or are you loading it with a relative path?

```
bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

**Notice the missing forward slash at the beginning**

Comment: I used second one.No slash.

Comment: That's the problem, loading a relative path loads **from** the current directory. Use the first and it should be okay.

Comment: My pleasure :) Enjoy the rest of your Node JS experience!