# Relative path to JS file changes when path is /reset_page/jwt.token.here

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Application was working fine until I changed this:

```
app.use(express.static("dist"));  

app.get(["/", "/page_1", "/page_2"], api_pages_get);
```

To this (I added a path on the second line):

```
app.use(express.static("dist"));

app.get(["/", "/page_1", "/page_2", "/reset_page/:reset_password_token"], api_pages_get);
```

Now the frontend HTML is not loading the desired JS file as it is referencing this:

```
http://localhost:3000/reset_page/js/bundle.js
```

Rather than this:

```
http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.js
```

So it is adding a directory to the relative path for some reason.

The specific error message in Chrome dev tools is:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)   Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:3000/reset_page/js/bundle.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

The format of the JWT token is:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1TiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ0.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTUzNDgzMzgyNn5.M8P0Xt92rKVmOximyyjgFISZc8hGFZA3eQjloRHGksB
```

Maybe a silly idea, but could the "dots" in the JWT token be confusing express in some way?

**Edit**

In case it is relevant, I am using the `simple templating engine` example, as described here:

https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html

```
res.render('index', { page_html: page_html, page_tagline: page_tagline });

app.engine('ntl', function(filePath, options, callback) { 
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, content) {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        var rendered = content.toString().replace('#page_html#', options.page_html).replace('#page_tagline#', options.page_tagline);
        return callback(null, rendered)
    })
})

app.set('views', './views')
app.set('view engine', 'ntl')
```

The js file is referenced like this in the template file `index.ntl`:

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
```

It was working fine until I made the change described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change this:

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

in the template `index.ntl` file (ie add a forward slash to the path).

Per these answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32673698

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22225942